# i can not use jquery select2 with json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, html, jquery-select2

i MVC4 and i want to add a select box that retrieve data (Product code) from my database the problem is that i have a message from select2.js telling select2 touppercase of undefined.

*all the JS file are uploaded.

here is my Jquery function:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Product_cd').select2({
         minimumInputLength: 2,
         ajax: {
             url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: function (term, page) {
                 return {
                     q: term
                 };
             },
             results: function (data, page) {
                 return { results: data };
             }
         }
     });
    });
 </script>
```

here is my controller AutoComplete

```
 public JsonResult AutoComplete(string q)
    {
        Mydb db = new Mydb();
        var Code = from c in db.Products
                   where c.Product_code.Contains(q)
                   select c.Product_code;
        var result = Code.ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


}
```

and here is part of the view:

```
            <div class="col-md-2">
       <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Product_cd )</div> 
       <div> @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Product_cd)<i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
      </div>
```

can any one tell me what is the problem

Comment: Are you sure there is an HTML element with id "Product_cd"? It is nowhere to find in your code. If it would miss, this could lead to having no valid select2 object and thus no object to call `touppercase`.

Comment: Yes there on in the Html.hleper

Comment: Read this before you post a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask